# Excel VBA Selecting all Rows with specific values in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I have a table with 1000 rows and 25 columns A through Y.
I am trying to create a macro that will select ALL rows in the table which MUST contain a "0" in the "I" column AND a "2" in the "R" column.

I would then like to get the data from the NEXT ROW UP from the selected rows in the first part of the macro. IF the value in columns "I" is ABOVE 0, sum up how many times and if the value is BELOW 0, sum up how many times.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub newCode()
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    nextValue As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    
    
    Do While Range("I" & i).Value = 0 And Range("R" & i).Value = 2
        i = i + 1

    Loop
    Range("I1:I" And "R1:R" & i - 1).EntireRow.Select
    'getting mismatch error
    
    Next
    nextValue = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value
    If nextValue > 0 Then
    'Need help here
    ElseIf nextValue < 0 Then
    'Need help here
    Else


End Sub
```

Comment: It would probably help if you included some screenshots of what you have and what you are hoping to have as a successful result.

Comment: also `Range("I1:I" And "R1:R" & i - 1).EntireRow.Select` doesn't really make sense. What's the intent? Get the two cells in each column when going through the rows? You also don't have `rng` assigned to a range.

Comment: @pgSystemTester I was attempting to select all rows that had a 0 in the "I" column and "2" in the R column, not get 2 specific cells. Then after selecting those, getting the value of the next cell just above in the "I" column if it is a 0 or a 1 and the count of how many times..

Answer (score 0):

here is something that does what you describe:

```
Sub newCode()
        
    Dim nextValue As Integer
    
    Dim row As Range
    Dim sel As Range
    
    Dim countPos As Integer
    Dim countNeg As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To 1000
        If Range("I" & i).Value = 0 And Range("R" & i).Value = 2 Then
            Set row = Range("A" & i).EntireRow
            If sel Is Nothing Then
                Set sel = row
            Else
                Set sel = Application.Union(sel, row)
            End If
            sel.Select
            
            nextValue = Range("I" & i + 1).Value
            
            If nextValue > 0 Then
                countPos = countPos + 1
            ElseIf nextValue < 0 Then
                countNeg = countNeg + 1
            End If
            
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Count of positive values: " & countPos & vbCrLf & _ 
           "Count of negative values: " & countNeg
End Sub
```

It processes exactly 1000 rows, selects the rows having a "0" in column I:I and a "2" in column R:R, and return (*) the count of rows that:

- are **just below** those selected rows ("2" in column I:I and "0" in column R:R)
- have a positive or negative value in column I:I.

(*) You might need to display the Execution Window in the Visual Basic Editor to see the result produced by the procedure.

Comment: Hey cedrcr4 thanks for the quick response. In the nextValue = Range("I" & i + 1).Value, I am getting a error 13 type mismatch. And do you mean returns the count of rows just "above" the previous rows?

Comment: Also, how so could i use a msgbox to display the results?

Comment: Hey ced so it's selecting all the correct rows but only until row 340? and is giving me the error run time error "13" mismatch error. When I press debug it highlights nextValue = Range("I" & i + 1).Value in the if clause.